# Setup docker-ce on Xeon E5-2680 v2

Tags: bash, docker, linux-vserver

I tried to install docker-ce on a vServer with Ubuntu 16.04.4 hosted at Strato, having a Xeon E5-2680 v2.

The error:

```
myuser@myserver:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce

...

docker-ce (18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu) wird eingerichtet ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2018-05-07 20:15:42 CEST; 8ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 22633 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22633 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes docker-ce (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
liberror-perl (0.17-1.2) wird eingerichtet ...
git-man (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3) wird eingerichtet ...
git (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3) wird eingerichtet ...
patch (2.7.5-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The script I got from [docks.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Is the error due to the vServer running on an Intel Xeon? What must be done to get docker-ce installed?

**EDIT 1:**

Output of `systemctl status docker.service`:

```
myuser@myserver:~$ sudo systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2018-05-07 20:15:43 CEST; 2min 40s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 22724 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22724 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
myuser@myserver:~$ sudo journalctl -xe

...

Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock" module="containerd/debug"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock" module="containerd/grpc"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.010838s" module=containerd
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.605595242+02:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support l
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.608090443+02:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support l
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.619662715+02:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.623483279+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.623510242+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.623523569+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.623531360+02:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.623565190+02:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.623620107+02:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22703]: Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.819275011+02:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=22731
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" module=containerd revision=773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88 version=v1.0.3
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.content.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotte
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs" error="/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.b
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter overlayfs in metadata plugin" error="/var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.ov
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.differ.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.gc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock" module="containerd/debug"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock" module="containerd/grpc"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42+02:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.008826s" module=containerd
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.856097907+02:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support l
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.858553040+02:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support l
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.866263584+02:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.868925885+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.868946286+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.868959706+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.868967403+02:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.869000999+02:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: time="2018-05-07T20:15:42.869043713+02:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Mai 07 20:15:42 myserver.stratoserver.net dockerd[22724]: Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

Comment: `See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`. What did that show?

Comment: What Geralds says but also "Is the error due to the vServer running on an Intel Xeon?" - 100% no.

Comment: First, you must look at the error messages to determine why it didn't start.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Sorry for the little delay. So, I re-ran the whole process and added the requested error files. Please check `EDIT 1`.

Comment: Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and try again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why upgrade? Are there known problems with Ubuntu 16.04? My local machine has Ubuntu 16.04 with an AMD Ryzen 5 and Docker runs perfectly.

Comment: I would advise against upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 as docker is not supported on this version as of the time of writing. It will probably soon will but currently is not supported and it's not working very well.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32334#issuecomment-291368359

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh So you think this error is created, because the Kernel doesn't offer an ´overlay´ functionality, that docker needs to start? Your issue link looks similar to my problem.

Comment: I think, that if strata uses virtualization software not supported by docker, such as openvz, this could be your problem.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Thanks, Andrew! That was the solution to the question. Strato only allows Docker for very few server types. A list of those is here (German): https://www.strato.de/faq/article/2427/Welche-Server-und-Betriebssysteme-bei-STRATO-sind-Docker-ready.html
I guess I'll have to move to another company then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strato uses OpenVZ for virtualization, and Docker [is not supported](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32334#issuecomment-291368359) on OpenVZ.

This is the [list](https://www.strato.de/faq/article/2427/Welche-Server-und-Betriebssysteme-bei-STRATO-sind-Docker-ready.html) of server types on Strato  indicating docker support.